# JSON unexpected token error (PHP json_encode & jsonlint.com)

Tags: php, json, jsonlint

```
{"cover":"http:\/\/files.domain.com\/some_file\/1234.jpg_thumb.png"}
```

This is my JSON code and when I tries to parse, it returns Unexpected Token error.
I checked on http://jsonlint.com/ but it didn't go well.

I used php json_encode function to encode JSON.

++ update
It works fine when I copy JSON string and paste it in Notepad or other plain text editors and re-copy that.
I think it must be some encoding error or something. I'll try.

Comment: What are you using to decode it?

Comment: Also, could you include the code that encodes the data, and also the code that decodes it?

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed it.
It was very simple to find out; I captured packet and view hex, and there's other byte in json.
My php file encoding was UTF-8 with BOM! I simply converted it to utf-8 without bom, and all is well.